# How do I get GPGMail to stop automatically enabling encryption options when I email people whose public keys are saved in my keychain?

Tags: macos, encryption, apple-mail, pgp

Title pretty much explains my problem. I like having the option to encrypt when I mail certain contacts, but that doesn't mean I want to do it every time — having to disable encryption 90% of the times I email my boss is kind of annoying.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing? I can't find the option to disable this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust the settings: Mail.app > Preferences > GPGMail > Composing > Encrypt when all keys are available.